# How To Style TreeViewItem Differently Depending On Level

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a `TreeView` that will be three levels deep that I've already created styles for.  When I hard code these three levels along with my custom styles, it works just as intended.  When I try binding to the TreeView, the levels are not rendered correctly.

**Hard Coded TreeView**

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="First Level" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemGroup}">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Second Level (a)" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemSubGroup}">
            <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
            <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
            <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Second Level (b)" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemSubGroup}">
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

**Hard Coded TreeView Image**
[image]

When I try to bind to a list and use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` each child isn't rendered inside of the parent like in the hard coded image.  Maybe I'm not going about this the right way?  Anyone have any clues?

**DataTemplates**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuSubGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Header}" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemSubGroup}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuSubGroups}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuSubGroupTemplate}">
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Header}" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemGroup}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**TreeView With Bindings**

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuGroups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuGroupTemplate}"/>
```

**TreeView With Bindings Image**

[image]

**================EDIT================**

I got most of it working but I'm still stuck on styling the top level.  To get the 2nd and 3rd level of `TreeViewItem` working I had to add the styles to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.  Now where do I specify the style for the topmost `TreeViewItem` level?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuSubGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Header} />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style><!-- 3rd STYLE HERE --></Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuSubGroups}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuSubGroupTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Header} />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style><!-- 2nd STYLE HERE --></Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to put each style inside of the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and the `TreeView`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemItem}" />
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuSubGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Header} />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style><!-- 3rd STYLE HERE --></Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuGroupTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuSubGroups}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuSubGroupTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Header} />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style><!-- 2nd STYLE HERE --></Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuGroups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuGroupTemplate}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style><!-- 1st Level Style --></Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to do it.